# How to prevent iteration over same attributes on jsp page

Tags: forms, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags, jspx

I have a jsp page like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> 

<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>    

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Page for find kids</title>

</head>

<body>

<a href="#" id="shlink"><h3 align="center">Parameters of search</h3></a>

<form:form action="result" method="get" modelAttribute="fbosAttribute" >

<table id="searchForm" align="center">

<tr id="dateId">
<th>Date:</th> 
<td><form:select  path="particularDate">
<form:option value=""> -Выберите дату-</form:option>
<form:options items="${listOfDates}"></form:options>
</form:select> <td><font color="#FF0000"><b><form:errors path="particularDate"/></b>     </font></td>
</td>    
</tr>   

<tr id="nameId">
<th>Name:</th> 
<td><form:select  path="nameOfInstitution">
<form:option value=""> -Выберите учреждение-</form:option>
<form:options items="${listOfInstitutionsNames}"></form:options>
</form:select></td> <td><font color="#FF0000"><b><form:errors path="nameOfInstitution"/></b></font></td>
</tr>

<tr id="typeId">
<th>Type:</th>
<td>
<form:select  path="typeOfInstitution">
<form:option value=""> -Выберите тип-</form:option>
<form:options items="${listOfInstitutionsTypes}"></form:options>
</form:select> </td> <td><font color="#FF0000"><b><form:errors path="typeOfInstitution"/></b></font></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="Find" id="searchBtn" />
</td>
</tr>

</table>

</form:form>  

<c:choose>


<c:when test="${empty dateAttribute}">

<h1 align="center">Insert parameterst for search</h1>

</c:when>

<c:otherwise>

<table  align="center" border="1" id="resultTable">

<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name of school</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Particular date</th>
<th>Day Scheduale</th>
<th>Work Scheduale</th>
<th>Rotation</th>
<th>Number of kids</th>
<th>Kids upper 3 years old</th>
<th>Kids under 3 years old</th>
<th>Kids go to school date </th>
<th>Kids admitted date</th>
</tr>
</thead>    

<c:forEach items="${institutionAttribute}" var="institutionVar">
    <c:forEach items="${dateAttribute}" var="creationDateVar">
        <c:forEach items="${srcAttribute}" var="schRotChildVar">    


<tr>
<td align="center">${institutionVar.nameOfInstitution}</td>
<td align="center">${institutionVar.typeName}</td>
<td align="center">${creationDateVar.particularDate} </td>
<td align="center">${schRotChildVar.dayScheduale}</td>
<td align="center">${schRotChildVar.workScheduale}</td>
<td align="center">${schRotChildVar.rotation}</td>
<td align="center">${schRotChildVar.numberOfChild}</td>
<td align="center">${schRotChildVar.childUnder3YearsOld}</td>
<td align="center">${schRotChildVar.childUpper3YearsOld}</td>
<td align="center"><fmt:formatDate value="${creationDateVar.childGoSchoolDate}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" /> </td>
<td align="center"><fmt:formatDate value="${creationDateVar.childAdmissionDate}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" /></td>
</tr>


</c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
        </c:forEach>


</table>

</c:otherwise>

</c:choose>   

</body>

</html>
```

So when I extract data not from this jsp, but from my main() method it works perfectly fine. What means that my implementation - dao class works stable. But when I use this jsp  it extracts the similar data over a 10 times. I think about this tag `<c:forEach>`, here is must be a problem occur. Please help my to solve it. What you suggest, maybe I do not need `<c:forEach>` tag, are there may be something different.

Answer (score 0):

If you write too much content using c:forEach then it will take time. From your example I found the complexity is **n cube**. Basically on the server side the html is generated and it is rendered on client side after server send it. As for example if you write **1000 row** in the page then a huge html page is generated on the buffer. If buffer size is large it takes time to flush it.

**Most important point is that response time depends on how much data you are writing**

So, for performance improvement you can do the following

- Try to avoid **n cube** complexity. Do , something in the **DAO** so that in the jsp page you can write on order **n** complexity.
- Do not render full data at a time. Instead render partial data and use pagination to fetch more.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Your answer with no doubt is really professional and it's hard even to understand. Whan is "n cube"? My dao works normal it's return anything what I need in order I prefer it to return in console, but now I need to put all this data to my table to make it looks like a table more accurate for user.I need iterate over them if I have more then one object to return as model attribute from dao. The one solution I found is iterate over them in jsp, but here is a problem that I can not even iterate over attribute's from dao correctly. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You are running 3 nested loops. For brevity I assume each loop operates on n items. Then n*n*n iteration will occur. That's call n cube time complexity. How many data your DAO is fetching ? If jsp has to render lots of data then its better to use pagination. Here is a simple example of pagination with jsp : http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/jsp/pagination-in-servlet-and-jsp/

Comment: MAK Ripon thank you so much for your answer. My dao maximum will fetch 40 lines and each line has 9 columns. This is maximum. I will look in this pegination example, this is looks as a way to solve problem.